# How to remove duplicate in combobox with database access

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I have a database like this:

```
Manufacture     Model No   Length  Width  Height 

Manufacture 1   MD-01      200     300    100
Manufacture 1   MD-02      300     400    100
Manufacture 1   MD-03      400     300    150
Manufacture 2   MAD-01     200     450    100
Manufacture 2   MAD-02     250     400    100
Manufacture 3   MDI-01     300     300    100
Manufacture 4   MOv-01     350     300    100
```

I would like to create 2 comboboxes, *Manufacture* and *Model No*.

*Manufacture* should display for the above example: Manufacture 1, Manufacture 2,Manufacture 3, Manufacture 4

When a particular manufacture is selected for example Manufacture 2 -> The *Model No* combobox should display only MAD-01 and MAD 02.

Based on both selections a text box must be loaded with length, width, height.

I tried sample code and assign the combobox with database values. I got duplicate values like this:

Manufacture 1
Manufacture 1
Manufacture 1
Manufacture 2
Manufacture 2
 
Manufacture 3
Manufacture 4

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: 1) I have edited your question, please spend more time on it next time (if you spell *combox* instead of *combobox* that shows insufficient effort). 2) Asking for external code is off topic here 3) **We need to see your code**. [Edit] your question. How can anyone answer what you are doing wrong if we can't see your code?

Comment: I havent written code. I need example code for above process to be done.When i created combobox. There is provision accumulate with daset value.I have added dataset value just run program where i found combox accumulated as above

Answer (score 0):

My form window look like this. I only added combo box then use databound items.
I need sample program to filter combobox without duplicate manufacture name. It should look like filter option in Excel.Provide Manufacture is merge & center while doing in excel.
Here it should show manufacture list with Filter value of model no

[image: My form Window]

[image: database image]